# How would I access this key within a JSON object in Java?

Tags: java, json, loops, iterator

I've been having some problems iterating through a JSON object in Java.
Specifically, I'd like to save each value for "name" to the string array "nameList". I've looked up how to do this, and I haven't found a way for this situation.

```
String[] nameList = new String[]{};
{
  "data": {
    "Narray": {
      "0": 
      {
        "_id": "001",
        "name": "studio",
        "date": "02141992"
      },
      "1": 
      {
        "_id": "002",
        "name": "venue",
        "date": "09041999"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Into what type did you parse the JSON into? @Kevin Baker

Comment: What particularly is tricky about this example?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd want Narray to be an actual JSON array, enclosed in [], with each element being another object, containing the property you need, like this:

```
  {
    "Narray": [
      {
        "_id": "001",
        "name": "studio",
        "date": "02141992"
      },
      {
        "_id": "002",
        "name": "venue",
        "date": "09041999"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Then you can use [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to decode the JSON string into a POJO structure. Once you have the objects, you can iterate over the array and retrieve the property you need into a list.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you only want to save each value of **name** into a `String[]` (string array), so you don't need to deserialize the JSON string to POJO, just use basic API to achieve what you want as follows:
BTW, your JSON string is invalid, you miss a right bracket.

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode nArray = mapper.readTree(jsonStr).get("data").get("Narray");

    String[] nameList = new String[nArray.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < nArray.size(); i++) {
        nameList[i] = nArray.get(String.valueOf(i)).get("name").asText();
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nameList));
```

Console output:

> [studio, venue]